# console game character placement

Tags: c#, console-application, ascii

So I'm still working on my game and I have been struggling with the character placement since day 1. I want to place an "@" symbol on my map where you, the player are. Once that "@" symbol moves, the map tile should be redrawn behind it. The issue here is that the map is drawn in ASCII (in the console) and specific map characters have specific colors (# uses `Console.Foregroundcolor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow` for example).

The map is stored in a .txt file and it is read character by character using streamreader. This is then stored in a two-dimensional array called "data" For applying color to this tile, the program checks which character it is in a switch statement and applies color accordingly.

This is the closest I've gotten to the proper character placement I would like to achieve:

```
        public static void DrawCharacter()
    {
        lastmapchar = data[oldy][oldx];
        Console.SetCursorPosition(oldx, oldy);
        Console.Write(lastmapchar);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write("@");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        ClearKeyBuffer();
        Randomnumber = 100;
    }
```

This draws the "@" character in white, but it also draws the "lastmapchar" in white, which causes the player to leave a white trail behind himself.

Removing the `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;` line causes the player to be the same color as the first tile it's on.

So my question is: How would I make the game write the "@" character in white, while redrawing the map behind it in the right color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do one of two things:

1. **Every time the player moves, redraw the map entirely.** This is a little unoptimized, since things that have been drawn well are drawn again without changing anything.
2. **Redraw the tile that the player was on *before* the movement with the right color.** Just do the following:

   ```
       public static void DrawCharacter()
   {
       lastmapchar = data[oldy][oldx];
       Console.SetCursorPosition(oldx, oldy);
       // Change foreground color here, like so:
       switch (lastmapchar)
       {
             case "#":
                 Console.Foregroundcolor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                 break;
             //.... etc
       }
       Console.Write(lastmapchar);
       Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
       Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
       Console.Write("@");
       Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
       ClearKeyBuffer();
       Randomnumber = 100;
   }
   ```